# Windup Installation of Java Custom Addon

Tags: java, maven, jboss, add-on, rhamt

Created custom jar is not being picked from the local repository.

Have created the required add-on. The only issue I am facing is when trying to install the maven is looking for the online repository instead of my local repository.

Comment: Be sure to include relevant tags in your question. Show us what you tried. Show us the code. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Kindly excuse me for not filling up the details. Though got my code working. Had not set the Maven Repo in my class path which was the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing this behavior because one of your repository isn't set up correctly.

Update your class path and set your Maven Repository in good place.

e.g. add the following entry to settings.xml:

```
<localRepository>/dev/m2repo</localRepository>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes the problem was with the Maven Path not set as the environment variable. Post it's setting everything is working fine now.